# Is Global.asax file in App_Code.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, global-asax, app-code

How do I deploy a Global.asax file? Does it get compiled in release mode to the App_Code.dll?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy only the `Global.asax` file and it will pick up the changes immediately. Just like changing the `Web.config` file.

From MSDN

> The Global.asax file, also known as the ASP.NET application file, is
> an **optional file** that contains code for responding to
> application-level events...
>
> The ASP.NET Global.asax file can coexist with the ASP Global.asax
> file. You can create a Global.asax file either in a WYSIWYG designer,
> in Notepad, or as a compiled class that you deploy in your
> application's \Bin directory as an assembly. **However, in the latter
> case, you still need a Global.asax file that refers to the assembly**.
>
> **When you save changes to an active Global.asax file, the ASP.NET page
> framework detects that the file has been changed. It completes all
> current requests for the application, sends the Application_OnEnd
> event to any listeners, and restarts the application domain.** In
> effect, this reboots the application, closing all browser sessions and
> flushing all state information. When the next incoming request from a
> browser arrives, the ASP.NET page framework reparses and recompiles
> the Global.asax file and raises the Application_OnStart event.

Comment: Oh so it doesn't have to be released? its just like web.config?

Comment: @chris added a section to my answer to address your question in the comment

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly deploy only `Global.Asax`. If you want then you can do it by editing DLL. If you are on MVC project then you can see `mvcapplication.cs` in DLL. There we can apply changes. Its worked for me. I have used .net Reflector with Reflexil 2.1.[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW81C.png)